# Nautilus doesn't remember sorting options in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: nautilus, 19.04

I'm using Ubuntu 19.04. Every time I open a folder, files are sorted depending on their names. I switch manually to modification date sorting. But everytime I open a new folder I have to do that again, as Nautilus seems not to remember last settings.

Comment: It seems that Nautilus remembers the sorting order of each folder. However, when you enter a **new folder** it defaults to ***Name*** ordering. After you change the sort order for this folder, it sticks to this order until you change it again. Is this something you do **not** want?

Comment: The problem was that it didn't remember the ordering after I closed the folder. The accepted solution works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work in all supported Ubuntu releases. First get default sort order:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.nautilus.preferences default-sort-order
'name'
```

Now change it to new sort order by modification date:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences default-sort-order 'mtime'
```

The list of all sort values allowed:

- by Name = `'name'`
- by Size = `'size'`
- by Type = `'type'`
- by Modification Date = `'mtime'`
- by Access Date = `'atime'`
- by Trashed Date = `'trash-time'`

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks. I added also the command gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences default-sort-in-reverse-order true in order to diplay it in reverse order (newer files on top)

Comment: command worked but did not have an effect for me in 20.04 to sort by type, even after re-opening Nautilus

Comment: I confirm the confirm of @kdarras. Does not change the sort order on 20.04!