# Nautilus' sorting issues in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nautilus, dconf, gsettings

I've changed the default sorting for Nautilus in [gsettings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1293905/nautilus-does-not-remember-sort-order-of-home-directory) and [dconf editor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/861333/how-to-open-nautilus-file-manager-preferences) to 'type', which Nautilus uses to correctly sort all of my other folders. For some reason it always wants to sort my Downloads folder to 'last modified'. Is there any way to have the Downloads folder stay sorted to 'type'?

Also, I'm not seeing the behavior [described here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1159937/nautilus-doesnt-remember-sorting-options-in-ubuntu-19-04) regarding Nautilus remembering the sort order of a folder after changing it and navigating away and then back to that folder. [Two users confirmed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1159937/nautilus-doesnt-remember-sorting-options-in-ubuntu-19-04) that a fix that worked in 19.04 no longer works in 20.04. A similar solution was offered [in this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1293905/nautilus-does-not-remember-sort-order-of-home-directory), but a solution has yet to be found for 20.04.

Is there a way to fix the sort order being remembered in 20.04? Fixing this might kill two birds with one stone. Or if there's a way to change Downloads to sort by 'type', that would work too.

Many thanks in advance!